# Error with partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working in blog web site project. I create partial view for blog post.

İt's _MainContent partial view

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Blog.Data.Model.Article>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <h3>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.ArticleTitle, "Index", "Article", new { id = item.ArticleId }, new { })
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="img">
            <img width="400" height="300" src="@string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}",item.ArticleImages.FirstOrDefault().ContentType,Convert.ToBase64String(item.ArticleImages.FirstOrDefault().Content))" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x=> item.Content)
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
}
```

And it's Index page

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Blog.Data.Model.Article>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Anasayfa";
}

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
    @Html.Partial("_SideMenuPartial")
</div>

<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.Partial("_MainContent", Model.FirstOrDefault())
</div>
</div>
```

When i started this program then happen

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Article_E29CF5FDD5B2D2829B35531643263744339081C99736858CE61DDB0981D557EE', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Blog.Data.Model.Article]'.
```

And i have a empty page.

Comment: Read the error-message: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Article', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'IEnumerable<Article>'` - it says everything.

Comment: reason is my english a little bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view is expecting a collection of `Article` objects:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Blog.Data.Model.Article>
```

You're passing it a single `Article` object:

```
@Html.Partial("_MainContent", Model.FirstOrDefault())
```

Instead, provide the view with the collection that it's expecting:

```
@Html.Partial("_MainContent", Model)
```

(or any subset of that collection, but still an `IEnumerable<Article>`)